# Jquery Timecube

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin someone developed, but it doesn't work in firefox.  The error message in firefox is not pointing me to the exact part of the code to try to fix it.  Here's the link of the jQuery demo

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Touch-enabled-jQuery-Timeline-Plugin-with-3D-Flipping-Effects-Timecube/

Here's the error in firefox  This works fine in safari and chrome

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined timecube.jquery-b8a2f220730affe4bf5ed06e0b8843af.js:249:4
```

Comment: The plugin has bugs in it.

Comment: Overall it's a good plugin.  I just want to know if someone can figure out how to get it to work using firefox.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because that plugin is not supported by Firefox.
See http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Touch-enabled-jQuery-Timeline-Plugin-with-3D-Flipping-Effects-Timecube.html . Read the paragraph above the heading 'How to use it'.

There is one more plugin which isn't the same as the one you mentioned, but might be of some use, see the demo http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Rotate-An-Element-with-3D-Flip-Effects-Flipper/ . In the demo, set the rotation to `right-slide` and set the depth to the lowest value.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Any idea what to change in the code to make it work for firefox?

Comment: @user2974739 If there might be some solution for Firefox, then the people who made it, might have solved the issue, so you should search for an alternative, if you can't find, then you will have to make one yourself or change your plan.